# Crash related to UITableViewController / UISearchDisplayController in MonoTouch/Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, crash, uitableview, xamarin, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm having problem to find the cause of random crashes in my app. The crashes only occurs when I build in release mode and run on a device like iPhone or iPad. Running in debug on simulator no crashes occurs. My guess is that the problem has something to do with these two lines in the crash log,

```
6   UIKit                           0x34a193d0 -[UISearchDisplayController _destroyManagedTableView] + 68
7   UIKit                           0x34a2195a -[UISearchDisplayController dealloc] + 94
```

I've uploaded the source code of my UITableViewController and the full crash log here, https://gist.github.com/Nordis/6128735

All help to track the cause of the crashes is much appreciated!

**Update**

I've now crated a bug report, I looked and the thread Rolf suggested in the comments. So I downloaded the test case, applied the fix. But still exactly the same crash and the stack trace is very similar to what mine looks like.

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=13703

Comment: Does the fix here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6769885/183422 help?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rolf, no that fix doesn't help. I've actually have that fix in my code but still no luck. I think you got CC:ed in a conversation I had using Xamarin mailing list about this problem.

I've tried with the fix, without the fix, using BeginInvokeOnMainThread around the fix and also InvokeOnMainThread. Still the app crashes after a while. Often after using it for about 1-2 minutes. And I think only when I compiled using release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution provided by Rolf at Xamarin was fairly simple, all I had to do was to move the code from Dispose() to ViewDidDisappear() in my UITableViewController,

```cs
public override void ViewDidDisappear (bool animated)
{
    searchController.SearchResultsSource = null;
    searchController.Delegate = null;

    base.ViewDidDisappear (animated);
}
```