# How to fix SIGABRT crash in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

StackTrace:

```
NavigationRenderer+ParentingViewController.Dispose (System.Boolean disposing)
NSObject.Dispose ()
NavigationRenderer.Dispose (System.Boolean disposing)
NSObject.Dispose ()
DisposeHelpers.DisposeModalAndChildRenderers (Xamarin.Forms.Element view)
IDisposable.Dispose ()
FormsApplicationDelegate.UpdateMainPage ()
FormsApplicationDelegate.ApplicationOnPropertyChanged (System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
BindableObject.OnPropertyChanged (System.String propertyName)
Element.OnPropertyChanged (System.String propertyName)
Application.set_MainPage (Xamarin.Forms.Page value)
PageModelCoreMethods.SwitchOutRootNavigation (System.String navigationServiceName)
BasePageModel.<NavigateToLoginPage>b__74_0 () // I think the problem is in this method
NSAsyncActionDispatcher.Apply ()
(wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate)
UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName)
Application.Main (System.String[] args)
```

This is the stack trace for a SIGABRT crash I'm getting in my iOS app using Xamarin.Forms 4.4.

I think the issue is coming from this method:

```
async protected virtual Task<bool> NavigateToLoginPage()
        {
            await LoginProvider.Clear();
            Platform.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () =>
            {
                CoreMethods.SwitchOutRootNavigation(CoreApp.LoginNavigationStack);
            });
            return true;
        }
```

because it's the last method that was called before the crashing II'm assuming but I'm not sure how to fix it. I've looked at some solutions online like:
[MonoTouch SIGSEGV crash using navigationcontroller and searchdisplaycontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708705/monotouch-sigsegv-crash-using-navigationcontroller-and-searchdisplaycontroller/6769885#6769885) and https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6546/finding-the-cause-of-sigsegv which I think are related, but they don't match my case exactly..

Does anybody know what to do about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Chung can you please post your full logs in pastebin or here for the crash and I'll help

Comment: @JamesMallon Unfortunately this is all I have, the StackTrace from AppCenter reporting the crash from one of our clients

Comment: The issue is occuring on the page where NavigateToLoginPage() is declared. My best guess is that your switchoutrootnavigation method is doing something very wrong. You should look to Navigate to the original login page another way.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to do that? @JamesMallon Or would that be impossible without you having all my coe

Comment: Sorry chung, fell asleep,  if you can post your code for the method: SwitchOutRootNavigation, i should be able to determine what the issue is

Comment: If I click "Go to definition" on VS2019, it takes me to the namespace FreshMVVM with only the signature, but clicking "Go to implementation" takes me to this.. public void SwitchOutRootNavigation(string navigationServiceName)
        {
            SwitchOutRootNavigationWasCalled = true;
            SwitchOutRootNavigationServiceName = navigationServiceName;
        }

Comment: @JamesMallon FWIW, I'm seeing the same issue.  I can't post my whole stack here but here are the relevant parts:

NavigationRenderer+ParentingViewController.Dispose
...
ObservableCollection1[T].RemoveItem (System.Int32 index)
Collection1[T].Remove (T item)
MasterDetailPage.set_Detail (Xamarin.Forms.Page value)
AppRootPage.SetActiveChannel
...
AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_0 (System.Object state)
NSAsyncSynchronizationContextDispatcher.Apply ()