# searchDisplayController being deallocated, crashing

Tags: ios, uisearchdisplaycontroller

At one point this was working fine and, obviously, something has changed. When I leave the viewController that loads the searchDisplayController my app is sending a message to a deallocated instance. The stack is why I believe it's the searchDisplayController:
[image]

Looking over my code, I'm not sure where it gets deallocated. I'd appreciate any ideas. Thanks.

**EDIT:
I should add that if I comment out my viewDidDisappear method, the crashes stop.**

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
        // save the state of the search UI so that it can be restored if the view is re-created
    self.searchWasActive = [self.searchDisplayController isActive];
    self.savedSearchTerm = [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text];
    self.savedScopeButtonIndex = [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex];
}
```

Here are the relevant bits:

```
@interface ShowAttributesViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>
{   
    IBOutlet UITableView *attributesTableView;
    NSString        *savedSearchTerm;
    NSInteger   savedScopeButtonIndex;
    BOOL            searchWasActive;   
}   
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *attributesTableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *filteredattributesArray;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *savedSearchTerm;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger savedScopeButtonIndex;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL searchWasActive;



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.filteredattributesArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[[[SharedAppData sharedStore] attributesArray] count]];

    if (self.savedSearchTerm)
    {
        [self.searchDisplayController setActive:self.searchWasActive];
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setSelectedScopeButtonIndex:self.savedScopeButtonIndex];
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setText:savedSearchTerm];

        self.savedSearchTerm = nil;
    }
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.searchWasActive = [self.searchDisplayController isActive];
    self.savedSearchTerm = [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text];
    self.savedScopeButtonIndex = [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex];
}

-(void)viewDidUnload {

    self.filteredattributesArray = nil;
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString];
    return YES;
}

- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller willUnloadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    [attributesTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: i know you said you already found a solution, but your example is also missing a couple of things:  your `viewDidUnload` and `viewDidDisappear:` should be calling `[super viewDidUnload];` and `[super viewDidDisappear:animated];` at the end of each respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging, like others, I found this post that resolves the issue.

[UISearchDisplayController autorelease crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758575/how-can-uisearchdisplaycontroller-autorelease-cause-crash-in-a-different-view-co)